# AES Encryption 256 ECB Mode

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I tried to encrypt my plain data `"hello"` with key `"01234567891234567890123456789012"` but the problem is my encrypted code is not the same with [the online reference](http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/).

Here is my android code written:

```
String smykey = "01234567891234567890123456789012";
String hellos = "hello";

SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(smykey.getBytes(), "AES");

Cipher cipher =  Cipher.getInstance("AES");//("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding");//("ECB");//("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(hellos.getBytes());
```

code produce,

```
android: 0x25 0x66...0x2d 0x87 (32 bytes)
ref:     0xa3 0xef...0x68 0x9f (16 bytes)
```

What's wrong with this Android code? someone I appreciate your help please?

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference for "hello", but you should always specify the encoding when calling `getBytes`.

Comment: That website does "autodetect" to see if your key and data are hex-encoded or not. Turn that off to match the Java code. But maybe your key is meant to be hex-encoded? Then you need to fix the Java code to decode it first.

Comment: even use byte[] hello = {'h','e','l','l','o'}; will produce the same encoded output

Comment: How to specify the encoding?

Comment: the key "01234567891234567890123456789012" is plain text not hex

Comment: @HanWhiteking Consider accepting answers that are helpful. 

To accept an answer click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer that is best, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)  See [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more detail.

Also please consider going back and accepting past answers, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)

Comment: where's the hollow mark??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The online reference is doing something different, the Android code produces the correct encrypted data.

The data `hellos` is not a multiple of the block size (16-bytes) so you must specify padding (PKCS#7).

Android is using PKCS#7 padding and `25669d21 dfd0fd6f cfef6cce 4ef12d87` is the correct result for AES with a 256-bit key, ECB mode and PKCS#7 padding.

`smykey` and `hellos` were converted to data using UTF-8 encoding.

It is a rare case where ECB mode is used, it is not secure, use CBC mode with a random iv (prepend the iv to the encrypted data). Do not return padding errors on decryption.

Use an HMAC or better yet a key extending function such as PBKDF2 to securely except a string passcode to a secure encryption key. Using a string directly as a key is not secure.

Comment: My language is not Java. The Android code produces the correct encrypted data.

Comment: Do you have another online reference that produces the same output as the Android code? (presumably the one in the question uses a different kind of padding)

Comment: I ran the `smokey` and `hellos` on my code and got the same result as the Android code. The online "reference" might be using PHP `mcrypt` which does not have PKCS#7 padding.

Comment: yup I change hellos to "0123456789abcdef"; I got syncronized output. So the android code output for input "hello" is correct 0x25 0x66...0x2d 0x87 (32 bytes) not the reference.

Comment: The online reference is null padding the input data instead of PKCS#7. I changed the data by adding nulls (0x00) to `hellos`: `"hello\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"` and got the reference result: `a3efa22c f78cd224 f2b90dac e4c8689f`. PHP mcrypt is abandonware that hasn't been updated in years and should be avoided, it was written by a bunch of Bozos.

Comment: now i tried my input  String hellos = "hellos123456789 " and key String smykey = "01234567891234567890123456789012"; output from android is 32 bytes long but my another terminal unit only generate the cipher 16bytes long. How to generate padding the byte 16 to byte 32 so that it equal to android ??

Comment: With a text string 16 character long "hellos123456789 " and PKCS#7 padding one full block (16-bytes) of padding will be added. For the "another terminal unit" specify PKCS#7 (or PKCS#5) padding. See [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7).

Comment: The another way round in android I can ignore the padding by using "AES/ECB/NoPadding" to break the code, but anyway I more favor if my terminal can concatenate this 16-bytes padding. It solved! thx again.